# Fabric API to get crashes, %'s, etc. for multiple games

Tags: google-fabric

Looking to fetch data for multiple games, such as the crashes, their callstacks, DAU, crash free % users, etc. Not sure if my google skills suck or Fabric actually doesn't have an API.

Does anyone know if there is such an API? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paul from Fabric here. Unfortunately, there's no API for fetching Answers or Crash-related data at this time. We're working on making a solution for this, so stay tuned!

Comment: Thank you for confirming, Paul!